# Render .net controls to string and get events to fire

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have this issue where I'm trying to generate HTML to display on the page that is coming from the database in form of a template that has different curly brackets that get replaced with dynamic content at run time. For example curly bracket {Content} gets replaced with a few checkboxlists, radiobuttonlists, textboxes and a submit button. The way I'm doing this is by creating controls dynamically and rendering them as string and then outputting that string to the browser. But what this does is, it doesn't recognise the events assigned to the controls when they are generated. I may be taking a wrong approach to the issue, but I don't really see how else this can be achieved. I have put up some sample code below to show what I'm trying to achieve. Please advise how to resolve this.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim PageContent As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        PageContent.Append("A lot of content from database laid out using HTML templates stored in database including the below mentioned button code.")

        '# To illustrate how pagecontent is built using lots of such controls rendered to string
        Dim SubmitButton As Button = New Button()
        SubmitButton.ID = "MySubmitButton"
        SubmitButton.Text = "Submit"
        SubmitButton.CssClass = "SubmitButton"
        'Page.Controls.Add(SubmitButton)        '# This line I thought would resolve the issue, but it doesn't as the .net form is not built at the time of page load
        AddHandler SubmitButton.Click, AddressOf ClickHandler

        PageContent.Append(RenderControlToString(SubmitButton))

        Dim Output As Literal = New Literal()
        Output.Text = PageContent.ToString()
        Page.Controls.Add(Output)

    End If

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Button Click Hander
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender"></param>
''' <param name="e"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub ClickHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    '# Control never gets here!!!!!
    Response.Write("<br/>Button Clicked!")
    Response.End()

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Render control to string
''' </summary>
''' <param name="control"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Function RenderControlToString(control As Control) As String

    Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
    Using sw = New StringWriter(sb)
        Using textWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
            control.RenderControl(textWriter)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return sb.ToString()

End Function
```

Thanks for advising!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dynamically loading controls in .Net is a little confusing.  I see four problems with what you're doing.

1. You're trying to dynamically add the controls only on the initial HTTP GET (not on postbacks).  You need to add the controls every time. You're not binding data here, you're adding controls to the Page control tree.  Those controls need to be added every time the page runs.
2. You're rendering controls to string.  Don't do that, just add them to the page control tree and they'll render on their own during the page Render.
3. Use Page.LoadControl() when creating controls.  This will create the control and force it's events (page event lifecycle) to catch up with the rest of the page.
4. You're adding controls a little late in the page event lifecycle.  Try adding your controls in Page_Init.

Here's a sample that pulls it all together.  It dynamically creates a button and then adds it to a placeholder control.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  var button = LoadControl(typeof(Button), null) as Button;
  button.Click += clickHandler;
  myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, it all makes sense. I'm just not sure how 2. would do the trick for my requirements. As I have mentioned in my question, the layout of the page to be displayed comes from the database and I need the control to be placed exactly where the curly bracket in the content is. So I'm loading the control as I build a string to display as output, if I don't do the render as string how would the control get placed exactly where I want it?

Comment: You can do what .net does.  Put your HTML in a Literal control and add it to the control tree. When you come across a button or a text field, create controls for those and add them to the control tree.  If you have more HTML after those controls then put that HTML in another Literal control and add that to the control tree.  It's not a fun way to build a page but if you're doing something a little crazy like building a page based on a string you're pulling from a database then you're going to experience a bit of pain making that work.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds challenging. The problem I'm having is reverse-engineering an existing classic ASP application in .Net. So the idea of HTML coming from database (done in classic ASP) cannot be changed because I need to make sure that the new application works exactly the same as the old one without having to make any changes. Also, the template is in a format like this "<table><row>{header_stuff}<row><row>{more_dynamic_stuff}<row><row>static html and other things<row><Some More Rows}</table>. So the curly bracket {more_dynamic_stuff} will have a bunch of controls.

Comment: Also, each control that gets added dynamically needs to have HTML before and after it which also comes from the database. Do you have any pointers on if there is an easier solution to the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if you caught it but I gave you the answer to how to deal with HTML in my previous comment.  If you want to deal with controls and have their events fire, that's the way you have to do it.  If you really just want to use strings (not controls) then you should look at something other than WebForms.  I think ASP.Net MVC would be a much better fit, plus it sounds like you're more familiar with classic ASP than ASP.Net, so MVC might be an easier transition for you.

Comment: I got what you were trying to say and as I said it sounds quite challenging to deal with the issue that way. So I was just wondering if there was any workaround. If not, I will just scan the template and add HTML until the first curly bracket to a literal control, when I hit a curly bracket, I will stop there and add required controls to the control tree, then start from the end of curly bracket and put html to a literal until the next curly bracket and go on until it's the end of the template. I suppose that's how you reckon it needs to be done. Right?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use controls that's how.

Comment: Alright, I have done that. Wasn't that hard really. RegEx to split the template into raw html + curly bracket tags. For each item with a match, adding a literal to placeholder and for each dynamic item adding an array of controls + literals to the placeholder. Good lesson learned! Thank you heaps!

Answer (score 1):

controls must be initiated in Page_Init to  persist them in viewstate and if control does not exist in viewstate, aspx won't understand whos event was registered. Initialize ur button on page_init

Answer (score 1):

Use the [PreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit.aspx) event, as explained here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx, this is where you will want to add dynamic controls. In fact you should just have to do the Page.Controls.Add() , since this is happening early enough in the page life cycle, ASP should handle the rendering for you.