# Create an asp server control dynamically in an html string, which is then inserted in an aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am on the server side of an asp.net application. There I have some html source code in a variable called 'HtmlText'. This source code is generated from xml via a xsl transformation, and is resulting in something like this:

```
<h1>ABC Test KH</h1>
<!--place for the control-->
<table class="tablesorter" id="tablesorter183">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th align="left">Name</th>
    <th align="right">DB</th>
    <th align="right">DB Anteil in Prozent</th>
    <th align="right">ABC</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td align="left" fieldName="Name">Fabrikam, Inc.</td>
    <td align="right" fieldName="DB">881.378,00 €</td>
    <td align="right" fieldName="DB_Anteil_in_Prozent">29,92</td>
    <td align="right" fieldName="ABC">A</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now this source code is inserted in a aspx-website via the InnerHtml-property.
There is a div with id 'book' in that aspx:

```
book.InnerHtml = HtmlText
```

This works fine so far.

But now I want to create a dropdown-control in that html, which I can access on server-side. This control should be placed between the h1 and table-tags, where the comment `<!--place for the control-->` is located.

I know how to create asp-control dynamically and bind an event to that, but this works only if I have the aspx in the first place. I cannot do that to some html-source which exists just in a string at that time.

Is there any way to do what I want, or am I on the wrong track here?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Kind regards,
Kai

Comment: Why do you generate html in the first place?

Comment: Because I got an xml from a database. Then I use several xsl-transformations to get the desired result, first as a xml, and in the last step (the one described) to produce html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only solution is to create a control that inherits DropDownList, and override its RenderControl method.

Something like this:

```
public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
      //...
      //Fill in the variable HtmlText content
      //Split it to 2 variables - before and after the control place, and:

      writer.Write(startString);
      base.RenderControl(writer);
      writer.Write(endString);
}
```

And use this control instead of DropDownList.

**EDIT:** In a case of several controls, I would use the way suggested here: [Render .net controls to string and get events to fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865241/render-net-controls-to-string-and-get-events-to-fire):

Split the string to several strings - the first string - from the beginning to the first control, second string - from the first control to the second control, and so on.

And then insert each of the strings to a new LiteralControl, and add them to the page Like this:

```
book.Controls.Add(LiteralControl1);
book.Controls.Add(DropDownList1);
book.Controls.Add(LiteralControl2);
book.Controls.Add(Button1);
```

Comment: So basically you insert all the generated html-code as part of the dropdown-control?

Comment: Yes, but I do not think it has any undesirable effect.

Comment: Hm... It prevents me from adding more than one DropDown, doesn't it? Because also the html-Code doubles, if I add another one...

Comment: You can add this control once, and other times a standard DropDownList control.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this solution is not suitable in case of several controls. In this case I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865241/render-net-controls-to-string-and-get-events-to-fire) can help you.

Comment: That seems like a suitable solution. I came up with another approach: I render the control inside the html-string, manually adding the javascript-postback-function, and later I just add the same control with Visible=false to the apsx, and bind events to it. The first control shows, the last does not, and the first one triggers the events of the second one. Your approach seems to be much cleaner, though. I will try, and tell you how it works.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. In my transformation I write comments into the html-string (with xsl:comment), representing my dropdown-control. Later I split up the html at that comment, and implement the dropdown as you suggested.